How to use the async function axios into setInteval or setTimeOut?
I tried to send data  regularly from react to laravel by using axios into setInterval, but it send an empty array.
Here is my code:
const consultationTable = useSelector(
  (state) => state.reducerConsultation.prods_consultee,
);
useEffect(() => {
  //pour les users authentifiees

  const envoiConsultation_prod = async () => {
    await Axios.post("/consultation-prod", {
      consultationTable: consultationTable,
    })
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);

        // dispatch(unload_for_next_sending())
      })

      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error.response.data " + error.response.data.message);
        if (error.response.data.message === "Unauthenticated.") {
          envoiConsultationGuest();
          setGuest(true);
          //console.log('ca marche')
        }

        console.log("erreur consultationTable:" + consultationTable);
      });
  };

  const intervalId = setInterval(envoiConsultation_prod, 10000);

  // return  a method in useEffect to clear the interval

  /* return ()=>{
  console.log('test on Unmounting');
  clearInterval(intervalId)


}  */
}, []);


It sent an empty array, but at first I called consultation_prod directly in useEffect with consultationTable in the array dependencies of useEffect, so it worked perfectly without any issue.

3 new lines and spaces between ) } don't make it any readable instead the opposite. edit it to be more sane and conventional or accept my edit which used Prettier
